# Android app keeps crashing, uncertain of the cause

Tags: java, android

I developed an app to help keep track and help with my daily routines. I have installed it as a system ap in /system/priv-app. The app runs without any issues except that it crashes every now and then, often times crashing in succession and then running without an issue for hours/days. I am not certain what is crashing it. Any help would be appreciated.

I have attached the relevant filtered logcat output. a.b.MyApp is my app and it is composed of a MainAct which as the name suggests is the main launcher activity, which spawns a foreground service named MyService which runs 24/7. MyService is started with START_STICKY and it is the service that crashes. When it does, android restarts it and much to my chagrin it restarts MainAct and MyService with MainAct displayed on the screen on top of any other app I may have open at the time and that was the clue that prompted me to investigate and thus helped me learn of the crash.

I would be happy to provide more info if needed.

```
06-20 12:41:06.462 W/ResourcesManager(1547): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:06.782 V/ActivityThread(28015): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{f791f2e token=android.os.BinderProxy@edb7ef6 {a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}} show : false
06-20 12:41:08.102 D/Recents_TaskView(1547): add blocking for a.b.MyApp of Close button
06-20 12:41:08.292 I/Timeline(5571): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:a.b.MyApp time:81061234
06-20 12:41:08.322 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:08.352 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:08.372 D/MyApp: MainAct-(28015): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@9a67acf, [I@678c5c
06-20 12:41:08.402 W/ResourcesManager(5635): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.android.packageinstaller rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:08.452 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{589bfca u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:08.472 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{589bfca u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:08.482 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:08.492 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:08.812 I/WindowManager(803): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{f152da4 ActivityRecord{43c3437 u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t90 f}} appWin=Window{589bfca u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct} drawState=4
06-20 12:41:08.852 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{589bfca u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
06-20 12:41:09.042 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 28015:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 (adj 11): remove task
06-20 12:41:09.082 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:09.092 I/WindowState(803): WIN DEATH: Window{589bfca u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:16.532 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:16.542 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:16.552 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:16.582 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:16.582 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:16.592 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:16.592 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:16.602 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:16.602 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:16.622 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:16.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:16.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:19.652 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:19.662 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:19.672 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:19.692 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:21.322 W/SELinux (5843): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp 
06-20 12:41:21.322 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 5843:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 for broadcast-3 a.b.MyApp/.GFReceiver
06-20 12:41:21.392 V/BroadcastQueue(803): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{348bfc3 u0 null qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{4394040 5843:a.b.MyApp/u0a232}
06-20 12:41:21.402 W/ResourcesManager(5843): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:21.422 W/System  (5843): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:21.442 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 5571:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 (adj 0): remove task
06-20 12:41:21.462 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:21.472 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:21.472 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:21.472 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:21.472 W/ActivityManager(803): Scheduling restart of crashed service a.b.MyApp/.MyService in 1000ms
06-20 12:41:21.472 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationRemoved : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:22.492 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 5862:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 for service a.b.MyApp/.MyService
06-20 12:41:22.502 W/SELinux (5862): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp:remote 
06-20 12:41:22.562 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:22.572 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:22.572 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:22.582 W/ResourcesManager(5862): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:22.602 W/System  (5862): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:22.602 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:22.612 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:22.622 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:23.942 I/Timeline(5862): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:a.b.MyApp time:81076886
06-20 12:41:23.952 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:23.962 V/WindowManager(803): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{ded951f token=Token{87df0be ActivityRecord{f740b79 u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t91}}} to stack=1 task=91 at 0
06-20 12:41:23.972 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : a670917 Starting a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:23.972 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:23.982 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:23.982 W/ResourcesManager(5843): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:23.992 W/ResourcesManager(5843): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:24.032 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{a670917 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:24.032 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{a670917 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:24.042 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{a670917 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:24.102 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{a670917 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:24.112 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5843): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@f675698, [I@cf25ef1
06-20 12:41:24.142 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : 3466607 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct
06-20 12:41:24.172 W/ResourcesManager(5635): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.android.packageinstaller rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:24.252 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:24.252 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:24.332 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{3466607 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:24.442 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{3466607 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:24.452 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5843): Permission: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS = PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
06-20 12:41:24.452 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5843): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@c587a1, [I@af3fdc6
06-20 12:41:24.452 I/Timeline(803): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{f740b79 u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t91} time:81077398
06-20 12:41:24.492 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{3466607 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
06-20 12:41:25.612 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{3466607 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:27.102 V/ActivityThread(5843): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{cd73c20 token=android.os.BinderProxy@eaffe62 {a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}} show : false
06-20 12:41:28.112 D/Recents_TaskView(1547): add blocking for a.b.MyApp of Close button
06-20 12:41:28.562 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 5843:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 (adj 11): remove task
06-20 12:41:28.592 I/WindowState(803): WIN DEATH: Window{3466607 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:28.602 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:32.262 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:32.272 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:32.302 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:32.362 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:32.382 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:32.392 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:32.412 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:32.422 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:32.422 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:35.442 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:35.442 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:35.462 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:35.472 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:35.502 W/SELinux (5976): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp 
06-20 12:41:35.502 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 5976:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 for broadcast-3 a.b.MyApp/.GFReceiver
06-20 12:41:35.562 V/BroadcastQueue(803): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{621ecf2 u0 null qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{7cfcf43 5976:a.b.MyApp/u0a232}
06-20 12:41:35.572 W/ResourcesManager(5976): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:35.582 W/System  (5976): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:35.602 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 5862:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 (adj 0): remove task
06-20 12:41:35.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:35.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:35.632 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:35.632 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:35.632 W/ActivityManager(803): Scheduling restart of crashed service a.b.MyApp/.MyService in 1000ms
06-20 12:41:35.632 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationRemoved : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:36.662 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 5995:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 for service a.b.MyApp/.MyService
06-20 12:41:36.672 W/SELinux (5995): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp:remote 
06-20 12:41:36.732 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:36.742 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:36.742 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:36.742 W/ResourcesManager(5995): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:36.752 W/System  (5995): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:36.772 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:36.782 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:36.792 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:38.092 I/Timeline(5995): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:a.b.MyApp time:81091035
06-20 12:41:38.102 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:38.112 V/WindowManager(803): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{1a90097 token=Token{6ce7f16 ActivityRecord{57efc31 u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t92}}} to stack=1 task=92 at 0
06-20 12:41:38.122 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : 6c56b8f Starting a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:38.132 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:38.142 W/ResourcesManager(5976): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:38.142 W/ResourcesManager(5976): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:38.172 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{6c56b8f u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:38.172 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:38.192 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{6c56b8f u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:38.212 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{6c56b8f u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
06-20 12:41:38.262 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{6c56b8f u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:38.272 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5976): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@f675698, [I@cf25ef1
06-20 12:41:38.312 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : b9e567f a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct
06-20 12:41:38.342 W/ResourcesManager(5635): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.android.packageinstaller rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:38.412 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:38.412 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:38.502 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{b9e567f u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:38.602 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{b9e567f u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:38.612 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5976): Permission: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS = PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
06-20 12:41:38.612 D/MyApp: MainAct-(5976): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@c587a1, [I@af3fdc6
06-20 12:41:38.622 I/Timeline(803): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{57efc31 u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t92} time:81091563
06-20 12:41:38.642 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{b9e567f u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
06-20 12:41:40.772 V/ActivityThread(5976): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{cd73c20 token=android.os.BinderProxy@eaffe62 {a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}} show : false
06-20 12:41:41.862 D/Recents_TaskView(1547): add blocking for a.b.MyApp of Close button
06-20 12:41:42.312 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 5976:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 (adj 11): remove task
06-20 12:41:42.342 I/WindowState(803): WIN DEATH: Window{b9e567f u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:42.352 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:46.512 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:46.522 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:46.532 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:46.592 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:46.602 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:46.612 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:46.622 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:46.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:46.622 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:49.672 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:49.672 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:41:49.692 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:49.702 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:41:49.722 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 6202:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 for broadcast-3 a.b.MyApp/.GFReceiver
06-20 12:41:49.732 W/SELinux (6202): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp 
06-20 12:41:49.802 V/BroadcastQueue(803): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{ba54a15 u0 null qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{331212a 6202:a.b.MyApp/u0a232}
06-20 12:41:49.812 W/ResourcesManager(6202): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:49.832 W/System  (6202): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:49.842 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 5995:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 (adj 0): remove task
06-20 12:41:49.882 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:49.882 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
06-20 12:41:49.882 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:49.882 W/ActivityManager(803): Scheduling restart of crashed service a.b.MyApp/.MyService in 1000ms
06-20 12:41:49.892 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:41:49.892 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationRemoved : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:50.902 W/SELinux (6245): SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=a.b.MyApp:remote 
06-20 12:41:50.902 I/ActivityManager(803): Start proc 6245:a.b.MyApp:remote/u0a232 for service a.b.MyApp/.MyService
06-20 12:41:50.932 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:41:50.942 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:50.942 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:50.942 W/ResourcesManager(6245): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:50.952 W/System  (6245): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/lib/arm
06-20 12:41:50.972 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:50.982 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:50.992 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:52.252 I/Timeline(6245): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:a.b.MyApp time:81105196
06-20 12:41:52.262 I/ActivityManager(803): isWidgetUsingPkg : a.b.MyApp no widget is using.
06-20 12:41:52.262 V/WindowManager(803): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2bffbe8 token=Token{91c010b ActivityRecord{46c28da u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t94}}} to stack=1 task=94 at 0
06-20 12:41:52.272 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : 3946000 Starting a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:52.302 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:52.322 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{3946000 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:52.322 W/ResourcesManager(6202): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:52.322 W/ResourcesManager(6202): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in a.b.MyApp rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:52.322 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:52.332 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{3946000 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:52.422 D/MyApp: MainAct-(6202): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@f675698, [I@cf25ef1
06-20 12:41:52.422 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{3946000 u0 d0 Starting a.b.MyApp}
06-20 12:41:52.452 D/ISSUE_DEBUG(803): InputChannelName : e411673 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct
06-20 12:41:52.472 W/ResourcesManager(5635): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.google.android.packageinstaller rsrc of package null
06-20 12:41:52.542 D/ActivityManager(803):  Launching a.b.MyApp, updated priority
06-20 12:41:52.542 V/MARsPolicyManager(803): updatePackagesScore PackageInfo name -- a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:41:52.622 D/StatusBarManagerService(803): manageDisableList userId=0 what=0x0 pkg=Window{e411673 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:41:52.712 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{e411673 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
06-20 12:41:52.722 D/MyApp: MainAct-(6202): Permission: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS = PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
06-20 12:41:52.722 D/MyApp: MainAct-(6202): Permission Error: [Ljava.lang.String;@c587a1, [I@af3fdc6
06-20 12:41:52.732 I/Timeline(803): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{46c28da u0 a.b.MyApp/.MainAct t94} time:81105670
06-20 12:41:52.762 V/WindowStateAnimator(803): Finishing drawing window Window{e411673 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
06-20 12:42:00.652 D/ApplicationPolicy(803): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = a.b.MyApp,userId = 0
06-20 12:42:00.662 W/ResourcesManager(1491): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/a.b.MyApp-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.android.systemui rsrc of package null
06-20 12:42:00.662 D/MARsPolicyManager(803): NotificationListenerService OngoingNotificationPosted : a.b.MyApp
06-20 12:42:00.692 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:00.712 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:00.722 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:00.732 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:00.742 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:42:00.742 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:42:03.772 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:42:03.782 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:42:03.792 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.812 V/BroadcastQueue(803): [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{df9288e u0 null qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{331212a 6202:a.b.MyApp/u0a232}
06-20 12:42:03.822 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.852 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.872 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.882 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.902 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.912 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:42:03.912 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=42 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=finishOp
06-20 12:42:03.912 I/AppOps  (803): sendInfoToFLP, code=41 , uid=10232 , packageName=a.b.MyApp , type=startOp
06-20 12:42:03.922 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:03.932 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(22489): a.b.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
06-20 12:42:15.852 V/ActivityThread(6202): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{31e2da9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@eaffe62 {a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}} show : false
06-20 12:42:17.172 D/Recents_TaskView(1547): add blocking for a.b.MyApp of Close button
06-20 12:42:17.582 I/ActivityManager(803): Killing 6202:a.b.MyApp/u0a232 (adj 11): remove task
06-20 12:42:17.612 I/WindowState(803): WIN DEATH: Window{e411673 u0 d0 a.b.MyApp/a.b.MyApp.MainAct}
06-20 12:42:17.622 D/ActivityManager(803): isAutoRunBlockedApp:: a.b.MyApp, Auto Run ON
```

Comment: Was it too hard to figure out or too little info ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar error.

Comment: Nope, my app still keeps crashing but not as many times as it did before. Ubale to get to the cause as there is not enough debug info in the logs.